# Reuse a cached spark dataset loaded in previous AWS EMR step

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am using AWS EMR and Spark for processing data on S3. My use-case is to access the same data in a new EMR step. Can this be achieved using `dataset.persist()`?

These are the set of steps:

1. EMR Step start
2. dataset = sqlContext.read().textFile("s3a://path/to/folder")
3. dataset.persist()
4. EMR Step complete
5. New EMR Step started
6. newDataset = sqlContext.read().textFile("s3a://path/to/folder")

In such a case, will Spark read all the data from the S3 path again or will it use the data available in-memory because of the call to persist()?

If not, is there another way of accessing the cached data?